# Перенаправка портов 80, 443 на порты 9450, 9560

Tags: windows, iptables, netsh

Как перенаправить все соединения с портов 80, 443 на порты 9450, 9560 без указания самого listenadress`а. На Linux Ubuntu делается вот так:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --destination-port 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Comment: Возможно вы неправильно понимаете что это за параметры. listen - это ваш локальный порт и адрес локального интерфейса, которые будут принимать входящие запросы и проксировать запросы на connect порт и адреса, которые могут быть на вашем компьютере или любом другом.

Comment: @dash1121 переформулировал свой вопрос.

Comment: 0.0.0.0 - любой локальный адрес